# run command from Python and then close

Tags: python, user-interface, windows-console

I am trying to build a small shell application, which runs a command from a GUI application. When I press the "off" button, the console for the command should be closed. I have two questions:

1. When I run the command, the command is running on the same console as my Python script. How can I open the command in a new console?
2. How can I stop the command? I mean like if the command is working in the same process as the GUI, I can just use `exit()`, but then the entire program will be terminated.

This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os

top = Tk()

def turnOn():
    p = subprocess.Popen("ping stackoverflow.com")

def turnOff():
    pass
    #should i do: p.close() of something?

on = Button(top, text = "on", command = turnOn)
off = Button(top, text = "off", command = turnOff)

on.grid()
off.grid()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try cmd's options, for example `'cmd /c "ping stackoverflow.com"'`?

Comment: The original question confused CMD with the console. I didn't see anything related to the CMD shell in particular, so I edited it to focus on the console instead. It's easy to get a new console with the argument `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the command by calling the subprocess's `.terminate` method. Here's a crude example that uses a global variable to store the `Popen` object; it would be better to wrap the GUI in a class, and store `proc` as an instance attribute of that class.

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

top = tk.Tk()

proc = None

def turnOn():
    global proc
    if proc is None:
        print('Starting ping')
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "example.com"])

def turnOff():
    global proc
    if proc is not None:
        print('Stopping ping')
        proc.terminate()
        proc = None

on = tk.Button(top, text = "on", command = turnOn)
off = tk.Button(top, text = "off", command = turnOff)

on.grid()
off.grid()

top.mainloop()
```

The `if proc is None:` line prevents the `ping` command from being re-launched if it's already running.

Comment: yes but if i am doing the command in new console, like: subprocess.Popen(command, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) then proc.terminate() wont close the new console.

Comment: @odri Ok. (I can't test that because I don't use Windows). But why do you actually _need_ it to run in a new console?

Answer (score 0):

> 1)when i run command, the cmd command is running on the same cmd that my 
>   pythoh script is work. how can i open the the command in another cmd window?

I assume you are trying to say that you need to run the process on another
shell. You should use the "shell" parameter of the subprocess functions:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

If instead you only need another command prompt window, just Popen another Windows cmd.

> 2)how can i stop the command? i mean like if the command is work on the same 
>   window that the gui work i can just use in exit(), but then the all programm
>   will be stop.

The subprocess Popen object has a terminate method. You can call this sending a SIGTERM signal but is not always reliable. So there are several options depending from your OS and the nature of your process
(a little note: Popen object has a pid attribute with process pid):

- **os.kill(pid, signal)** => to kill a simple process on a Posix/Windows OS
- **os.killpg(pgid, signal)** => to kill a process as a group on a Unix OS
- **subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /T /PID %i" % pid, shell=True)** => to kill a process on windows

signal is a posix/windows signal depending from the OS. I.e. :

```
os.killpg(self.pid, signal.SIGKILL)     # Posix
os.kill(self.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)  # Windows
```

The os.kill call is not always reliable on Windows. This is the reason
for using the third option.

Comment: CMD is not the console; it executes a REPL just like python.exe does when run interactively. A command-line shell or REPL reads from stdin and writes to stdout and stderr. It doesn't implement them, and it doesn't know anything about windows, window messages, mouse input etc. Spawning a new cmd.exe instance inherits the current console. To create a new console (i.e. an instance of conhost.exe), use the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. CMD isn't involved with this, unless you need to run a batch file or have it execute a command-line.

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals. Python's `os.kill()` implementation on Windows is a hybrid function. On one level it acts like `os.killpg`. If you're attached to the same console as the child process, and you created the process with `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`, i.e. its process ID is also a process group ID, you can send it a console control event, i.e. `CTRL_C_EVENT` (0) or `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` (1), but Ctrl+C will be disabled by default, so only Ctrl+Break is reliable. This calls WinAPI `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`. Passing an ID that isn't a process group ID is undefined behavior.

Comment: Sending a control event to process group 0 broadcasts the event to all processes attached to the console, including your own process.

Comment: For any value other than the two console control events, `os.kill` calls WinAPI `TerminateProcess`. This is equivalent to a Unix `SIGKILL`. The process is abruptly terminated without any chance to exit gracefully.

Comment: I'm fine with your explanations. If you like, you can edit my answer and you can freely add your contribute, Thank you!